# Proportional spaces between img with CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I am learning HTML and CSS. I have set up some logos but I need symmetry between the images and the borders. I have tried with float, margin, vertical align. But I can´t figure it out.

```
<div class="images">
<img src="img/whatsapp-png.png" width="100px" height="100px"/>
<img src="img/skype-png.png" width="130px" height="100px"/>
<img src="img/messenger-png.png" width="100" height="100px"/>
<img src="img/meet-png.png" width="100" height="100px"/>
<img src="img/zoom-png.png" width="150" height="70px"/>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h775z.jpg)

As you can see in the picture, I am showing the border to let you know what I am talking about.

If anybody has the answer I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Pd: English in process, sorry for grammar mistakes.

Comment: [Look into flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for your `div`. You can use that to keep everything neat. It'll probably end up looking like `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content:space-evenly;`

Comment: Great!!! thank you very much @chriskirknielsen . It works! What if I want the img closer? I mean less space between them. Is that possible?

Comment: `space-evenly` distributes the available space. If you want to dig into controlled "gaps", the recent addition of the `gap` in modern browsers should get you there, in addition to `justify-content: center`.

Comment: perfect @chriskirknielsen. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like your images are the problem. They might have an border on the imgage itself. Try removing them.

Comment: you mean remove the images´ borders? what is the command?

Comment: no i mean the imagefile itself. Most logos have an transparent border. U might need to remove them with an image-editing-tool like gimp.